# Can't solve JavaScript error, crumby code

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

I was tasked with updating a website for client, he told me that he needed to have the site redesigned for someone.

I keep getting an error on line 29 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined'

I've done about over an hour of troubleshooting and can't seem to solve it, please send help. btw the code was minified and I unminified it.

```
$("#math-captcha").mathCaptcha({
  imgPath: "src/img/",
  operation: "plus",
  introText: "Please enter the result of equation:",
  successFunction: function() {
    form = $("form"), $("#but").append('<button type="submit" style="margin-top: 20px;" class="btn btn-primary btn-md">Send Message</button>'), $(".math-captcha-error").remove()
  },
  failFunction: function() {
    form = $("form"), $("#butt").remove(), $(".math-captcha-error").length < 1 && $("#math-captcha").append("<p class='math-captcha-error'>Wrong result!</p>")
  }
}), $("#p-arrow").click(function() {
  $("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop: $("#about2").offset().top
  }, 1e3)
}), $("#header-arrow").click(function() {
  $("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop: $("#about").offset().top
  }, 1e3)
}), (new WOW).init(),
function(t) {
  "use strict";
  t(document).ready(function() {
    t(window).scroll(function() {
      t(window).scrollTop() >= 100 ? t("img.affix-top").css("display", "none") : t("img.affix-top").css("display", "block")
    })
  }), t("a.page-scroll").bind("click", function(a) {
    var o = t(this);
    t("html, body").stop().animate({
      scrollTop: t(o.attr("href")).offset().top - 50
    }, 1250, "easeInOutExpo"), a.preventDefault()
  }), t("body").scrollspy({
    target: ".navbar-fixed-top",
    offset: 51
  }), t(".navbar-collapse ul li a:not(.dropdown-toggle)").click(function() {
    t(".navbar-toggle:visible").click()
  }), t("#mainNav").affix({
    offset: {
      top: 100
    }
  }), window.sr = ScrollReveal(), sr.reveal(".sr-icons", {
    duration: 600,
    scale: .3,
    distance: "0px"
  }, 200), sr.reveal(".sr-button", {
    duration: 1e3,
    delay: 200
  }), sr.reveal(".sr-contact", {
    duration: 600,
    scale: .3,
    distance: "0px"
  }, 300), t(".popup-gallery").magnificPopup({
    delegate: "a",
    type: "image",
    tLoading: "Loading image #%curr%...",
    mainClass: "mfp-img-mobile",
    gallery: {
      enabled: !0,
      navigateByImgClick: !0,
      preload: [0, 1]
    },
    image: {
      tError: '<a href="%url%">The image #%curr%</a> could not be loaded.'
    }
  })
}(jQuery);
```

Comment: It seems as if `t(o.attr("href")).offset()` does not have a `top` property

Comment: `t(o.attr("href")).offset()` is returning `undefined`, hence calling the `top()` method on that throws an error. Most likely that `t(o.attr("href"))` itself isn't being found in the DOM. You'll need to debug why that is exactly, as there's not enough information in the question for someone to diagnose it any further

Comment: Can you show us the HTML it's interacting with too please

Comment: Offtopic: If the code was minified and you're expected to "fix it", then you should request the original, pre-minification version.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/MqzjYWJe

Comment: I solved the problem

Comment: @DilionSmith Add an answer with the solution for future readers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like your call to `t(o.attr("href"))` does not match an HTML element and so the call to `offset()` returns undefined, producing the error mentionend when trying to access property `top`.

I'm looking at your HTML code and there is no element with `id="page-top"`, so that is why it is failing. Make sure you have an element with `id="page-top"`!

Comment: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: anchor#
I got this error back.

Comment: You are right, I forgot that the "#" is already present on the href. I'm looking at your code now, and I don't see any element with id equals "#page-top", so that's why you are getting undefined when clicking on the link